# Create gzip chunk with given size (padded)

Tags: unix, gzip, padding

Imagine I have some text, like 'Feef'.
I can gzip it and the result is 24 bytes.
Is there a way to gzip it so the result would be 1024 bytes? It should be still a valid gzip stream, i.e. it would not generate the message "trailing garbage ignored" when decompressed.

How would I use it: Gzip data header to fixed size. Append gzipped data body. Update header, gzip it to same fixed size and overwrite.

You can concatenate gzip streams and it will still be valid gzip, but they have to be proper streams. Maybe there's a way to pad gzip output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gzip header permits an extra field of up to 65535 bytes that can contain arbitrary data and that is ignored when decompressing.  So you can change the gzip header to insert an extra field to pad out the file to the desired length.  See [RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952) for the format description.  If you don't care about the file name in the gzip header, you can make that *any* length, to pad to an arbitrarily large size.  Or if you want more than 64K and you don't want to muck with the file name, you can append empty gzip streams to make it as long as you like.